# Adding a nic to my Windows 10 VM in Azure

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

First of all, I would like to let you guys know that I am a novice in Azure (about 4 months).  I have created a Windows 10 VM, along with two nics attached to it (myNic1, myNic2).  Then I decided to create a nsg rule that allow rdp on port 3389 and created a public IP that I tried to no avail to assign to myNic1.

The error message I kept on getting was:

```
Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/WindowsVMPublicIP referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/myNic1 was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.
```

I am 400% sure that both resources are within the same region (WestUS) and that myNic1 already exists.

I don't know if it is a bug from Microsoft or am I going crazy. I followed the same steps with a Linux VM and did not have any issues. Please help.